# Refactoring with C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring

Given the new toolset provided by c++ lots of programmers, aiming at code simplification, expressiveness, efficiency, skim through their old code and make tweaks (some pointless, some successful) to achieve their goals. Whilst trying not to loose too much time on such labors and just make non intrusive and self contained changes, what are the best practices?

Let me cross out the obvious :

- Use **auto** to run iterator based loops :

  ```
  for (std::vector<foo>::const_iterator it(lala.begin()), ite(lala.end()); it != ite;     
  ++it);
  // becomes
  for (auto it(lala.cbegin()), ite(lala.cend()); it != ite; ++it);
  ```
- Use **tie** for multiple assignments that just produce C-style rows of code ( [how to assign multiple values into a struct at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269825/how-to-assign-multiple-values-into-a-struct-at-once/21513616#21513616) )

  ```
  a = 1;
  b = 2; 
  c = 3;
  d = 4; 
  e = 5;
  // becomes
  std::tie(a, b, c, d, e) = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  ```
- To make a class non inheritable just declare it as "final" and delete the code that achieved such a behavior http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/final-classes.html
- Use the delete keyword to explicitly hide constructors/destructors instead of declaring them private (eg code to create heap based objects, non copyable objects etc)
- Turn trivial functors created just to facillitate the execution of a single STL algorithm into **lambda** functions (apart from reducing code cluttering you'll have guaranteed inlined calls)
- Simplify RAII wrapping of an object by just using a **smart pointer**
- Get rid of bind1st, bind2nd and just use **bind**
- Replace hand written code for type traits (Is_ptr_but_dont_call_for_const_ptrs<> and such :) ) with standard code provided by **< type_traits >**
- Stop including boost headers for functionallity now implented in STL (BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT vs static_assert)
- Provide move semantics to classes (although this wouldn't qualify as a dirty/quick/easy change)
- Use **nullptr** where possible instead of the NULL macro and get rid of the code that filled containers of pointers with 0's casted to object type

  ```
  std::vector<foo*> f(23);
  for (std::size_t i(0); i < 23; ++i)
  { f[i] = static_cast<foo*>(0); }
  // becomes
  std::vector<foo*> f(23, nullptr);
  ```
- Clear the vector data accessing syntax

  ```
  std::vector<int> vec;
  &vec[0];    // access data as a C-style array
  vec.data(); // new way of saying the above
  ```
- Replace throw() with **noexcept** (apart from avoiding the deprecated exception specifiation you get some speed benefits http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler @ 00.29.42)

  ```
  void some_func() noexcept; // more  optimization options
  void some_func() throw();  // fewer optimization options
  void some_func() ;         // fewer optimization options
  ```
- Replace code where you'd push a tempory in a container and hoped that the optimizer would ellide the copy away, with an **"emplace"** function where available, in order to perfectly forward the argument and construct directly an object into a container without temporary at all.

  ```
  vecOfPoints.push_back(Point(x,y,z)); // so '03
  vecOfPoints.emplace_back(x, y, z);   // no copy or move operations performed
  ```

### UPDATE

[The answer by Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519186/2567683) was rightfully awarded the bounty for having the greatest acceptance by the audience.

[The answer by R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22802574/2567683) was my accepted one, because the **combination** of features it proposes captures the [**spirit of refactoring**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsRefactoring) :  making code clearer and cleaner and simpler and elegant.

Comment: *please* don't close this. it's really useful.

Comment: None of above is an improvement to an existing (correct working) library (they are semantic improvements), besides removing a dependency to boost and move semantics

Comment: Even this will be really opinion-based reopen it (due to popular demand)

Comment: I don’t see how this is “primarily opinion-based”. At all. However, it’s one of these big-list kind of questions that also don’t really fit the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what C++ idioms are deprecated in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299101/what-c-idioms-are-deprecated-in-c11)

Comment: There is a catch about using `.data()` instead of `&container[0]`. It will NOT work for `std::string` if you wish to modify the internal data. Why because `.data()` for `std::string` is the same as `.c_str()` and returns a constant pointer. Also for MSVC2013, `push_back` takes a `T&&` and is the same as `emplace_back`.

Comment: Use `override` to indicate that a function overrides a virtual function in base class instead of introducing a new one/hiding function in base class. Also I would advise against making every class you can a final. It should be used sparingly, because it can make testing the code more painful than it has to be.

Comment: `vector` data access worked well enough earlier, the same way as now guaranteed for `std::string`, so no reason to use `data()` at all. Also, they could have made `NULL` better instead of introducing the longer `nullptr`. There's a useless difference to C.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It may be useful but it's more like a blog post than an SO question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would add delegating constructors and in-class member initializers to the list.

**Simplification By Using Delegating Constructors and In-Class Initialization**

With C++03:

```
class A
{
  public:

    // The default constructor as well as the copy constructor need to 
    // initialize some of the members almost the same and call init() to
    // finish construction.
    A(double data) : id_(0), name_(), data_(data) {init();}
    A(A const& copy) : id_(0), name_(), data_(copy.data_) {init();}

    void init()
    {
       id_ = getNextID();
       name_ = getDefaultName();
    }

    int id_;
    string name_;
    double data_;
};
```

With C++11:

```
class A
{
  public:

    // With delegating constructor, the copy constructor can
    // reuse this constructor and avoid repetitive code.
    // In-line initialization takes care of initializing the members. 
    A(double data) : data_(data) {}

    A(A const& copy) : A(copy.data_) {}

    int id_ = getNextID();
    string name_ = getDefaultName();
    double data_;
};
```

Answer (score 31):

**1. Replacing rand**

One of the big gains in C++11 has to be replacing the use of `rand()` with all the options available in the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Replacing `rand()` in many cases should be straight forward.

*Stephan T. Lavavej* probably made this point the strongest with his presentation [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). The examples show a uniform integer distribution from `[0,10]` using `rand()`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    srand(time(0)) ;

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
            std::cout << (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (10 + 1) + 1)) << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

and using [std::uniform_int_distrubution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 10);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dist(e2) << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

Along with this should be moving from [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) which comes out of the effort to [Deprecate rand and Friends](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3775.pdf). This was recently covered in the SO question [Why are std::shuffle methods being deprecated in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600100/why-are-stdshuffle-methods-being-deprecated-in-c14/22600264#22600264).

Note that the distributions are not guaranteed to be [consistent across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26538627/1708801).

**2. Using std::to_string instead of std::ostringstream or sprintf**

C++11 provides [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) which can be used to convert numerics to [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) it would produce the content as the equivalent [std::sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Most likely this would be used in place of either [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) or `snprintf`. This is more of a convenience, there is probably not much of performance difference and we can see from the [Fast integer to string conversion in C++](http://zverovich.net/2013/09/07/integer-to-string-conversion-in-cplusplus.html) article there are probably much faster alternatives available if performance is the main concern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream mystream;  
    mystream << 100 ;  
    std::string s = mystream.str();  

    std::cout << s << std::endl ;

    char buff[12] = {0};  
    sprintf(buff, "%d", 100);  
    std::string s2( buff ) ;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl ;

    std::cout << std::to_string( 100 ) << std::endl ;
}
```

**3. Using constexpr in place of template meta-programming**

If you are dealing with literals there may be cases where using constexpr functions over template meta-programming may produce code that is more clear and possibly compiles faster. The article [Want speed? Use constexpr meta-programming!](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/07/want-speed-use-constexpr-meta.html) provides an example of prime number determination using template meta-programming:

```
struct false_type 
{
  typedef false_type type;
  enum { value = 0 };
};

struct true_type 
{
  typedef true_type type;
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template<bool condition, class T, class U>
struct if_
{
  typedef U type;
};

template <class T, class U>
struct if_<true, T, U>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template<size_t N, size_t c> 
struct is_prime_impl
{ 
  typedef typename if_<(c*c > N),
                       true_type,
                       typename if_<(N % c == 0),
                                    false_type,
                                    is_prime_impl<N, c+1> >::type >::type type;
  enum { value = type::value };
};

template<size_t N> 
struct is_prime
{
  enum { value = is_prime_impl<N, 2>::type::value };
};

template <>
struct is_prime<0>
{
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template <>
struct is_prime<1>
{
  enum { value = 0 };
};
```

and using constexpr functions:

```
constexpr bool is_prime_recursive(size_t number, size_t c)
{
  return (c*c > number) ? true : 
           (number % c == 0) ? false : 
              is_prime_recursive(number, c+1);
}

constexpr bool is_prime_func(size_t number)
{
  return (number <= 1) ? false : is_prime_recursive(number, 2);
}
```

The constexpr version is much shorter, easier to understand and apparently performs much better than the template meta-programming implementation.

**4. Using class member initialization to provide default values**

As was recently covered in [Has the new C++11 member initialization feature at declaration made initialization lists obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149924/has-the-new-c11-member-initialization-feature-at-declaration-made-initializati) class member initialization can be used to provide default values and can simplify cases where a class has multiple constructors.

[Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) provides a good example in the C++11 FAQ, he says:

> This saves a bit of typing, but the real benefits come in classes with multiple constructors. Often, all constructors use a common initializer for a member:

and provides an example of members which have a common initializer:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(): a(7), b(5), hash_algorithm("MD5"), s("Constructor run") {}
    A(int a_val) : a(a_val), b(5), hash_algorithm("MD5"), s("Constructor run") {}
    A(D d) : a(7), b(g(d)), hash_algorithm("MD5"), s("Constructor run") {}
    int a, b;
  private:
    HashingFunction hash_algorithm;  // Cryptographic hash to be applied to all A instances
    std::string s;                   // String indicating state in object lifecycle
};
```

and says:

> The fact that hash_algorithm and s each has a single default is lost in the mess of code and could easily become a problem during maintenance. Instead, we can factor out the initialization of the data members:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(): a(7), b(5) {}
    A(int a_val) : a(a_val), b(5) {}
    A(D d) : a(7), b(g(d)) {}
    int a, b;
  private:
    HashingFunction hash_algorithm{"MD5"};  // Cryptographic hash to be applied to all A instances
    std::string s{"Constructor run"};       // String indicating state in object lifecycle
};
```

Note, that in C++11 a class using in class member initializers is [no longer an aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) although this restriction is removed in C++14.

**5. Use fixed width integer types from cstdint instead of hand rolled typedefs**

Since the C++11 standard uses C99 as a normative reference we get [fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), as well. For example:

```
int8_t
int16_t 
int32_t 
int64_t 
intptr_t
```

Although several of them an optional, for the exact width integer types the following from C99 section `7.18.1.1` applies:

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8,
>   16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that
>   have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the
>   corresponding typedef names.

Comment: It seemed a bit of an overkill at first, but after watching the presentation I admit there a lot of issues I wasn't aware about. Great code impovent this one.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou considering your bounty does my answer not provide enough details? If so what details do you want to see?

Comment: The bounty was offered to motivate more answer and techniques being revealed and have more people commenting on what they use and what works or not. Your answer is both thorough and usefull; I don't think it needs improvement and from the way it looks it will remain the most popular and win the bounty

Comment: @Nikos Athanasiou totally agreed. I like his answer. Usually when this happened (you have another example to complement and/or upgrade an answer) I would just give a citation like "In order to complement previous answer given by Vin..., here is... ". But don't forget that prior to C++11 things like Fibbonaci calculation or pow or small numbers were done using template metaprogramming, so our answers are not that different.

Answer (score 12):

For-each syntax:

```
std::vector<int> container;

for (auto const & i : container)
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: I can not understand why people still prefer iterator based for loops, for_each with lambdas etc. Range based for loop results less code, and it is obviously easier to read.

Comment: @MuratŞeker: It's a lot easier when you have **two** iterators to **two** equally-sized containers.

Comment: Well, you can't use range-based iteration when you have to modify the container as you traverse it, and iterators give more control in general. Other than that I see no reason not to use them.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517399/c-range-for-loops-with-custom-step two drawbacks of ranged for are mentioned. That been said, it is indeed a good practice for non compicated loops to use the "new" way.

Comment: BTW `std::endl` causes a buffer flush to the console buffer. Often `"\n"` is much faster.

Answer (score 11):

1. Changing `std::map` to `std::unordered_map` and `std::set` to
   `std::unordered_set` where ever order of container's elements is irrelevant, enhances significantly the performance.
2. Using `std::map::at` instead of using square bracket syntax insertion, when you want to avoid involuntary insertions.
3. Use alias templates when you want to `typedef` templates.
4. Use of initialization lists instead of for loops to initialize STL containers.
5. Replace fixed size C arrays with std::array.

Comment: `std::uordered_set` -> here is a typo. 1. This change could enhance performance only for the maps and sets which are large enough (otherwise it will only reduce the efficiency of the program). Also it could reduce performance in case of iterating over such containers.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [uniform initialization syntax](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init)
for [variable initialization](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)

```
widget w(x); // old
widget w{x}; // new
```

to avoid problems like [c++'s most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/3316811) (the rest of the reasons why the new way is superior are explained in the linked article by Herb Sutter)

Comment: This is a great idea unless `widget` has a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 9):

This blog post proposes the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) if all ownerships into a class follow the RAII principle, allowing to get rid of the Rule of Three/Four/Five in C++11.

However, Scott Meyers shows [here](https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/a-concern-about-rule-of-zero.html) that not writing explicitly the destructor, copy/move constructors and assignment operators can induce subtle problems if you slightly change your code (say, for debugging). He then recommends to explicitly declare **default** (C++11 feature) these functions:

```
~MyClass()                           = default;
MyClass( const MyClass& )            = default;
MyClass( MyClass&& )                 = default;
MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& ) = default;
MyClass& operator=( MyClass&& )      = default;
```

Answer (score 7):

Feature: **std::move**

"Express clear difference between the copying and moving the resources"

```
std::string tmp("move");
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back(std::move(tmp));
//At this point tmp still be the valid object but in unspecified state as
// its resources has been moved and now stored in vector container.
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that `tmp` is "in empty state" after being moved from, only that it is an a "valid but unspecified" state. (In fact, a high quality string implementation with small object optimization will likely leave `tmp` unchanged.)

Answer (score 6):

1. **Prefer scoped enums to unscoped enums**

   - In C++98 the enums, there is no scoped for enums like the following code snippet. The names of such enumerators belong to the scope containing enum, namely nothing else in that scope may have the same name.

     ```
     enum Color{ blue, green, yellow };
     bool blue = false;    // error: 'blue' redefinition
     ```

     However, in C++11, the `scoped enums` can fix this issue. `scoped enum` are declared var `enum class`.

     ```
     enum class Color{ blue, green, yellow };
     bool blue = false;     // fine, no other `blue` in scope
     Color cc = blue;       // error! no enumerator `blue` in this scope
     Color cc = Color::blue; // fine
     auto c = Color::blue;  // fine
     ```
   - The enumerators of `scope enums` are more strongly typed. But, the enumerators of `unscoped enums` implicitly convert to other types

     ```
     enum Color{ blue, green, yellow };
     std::vector<std::size_t> getVector(std::size_t x);
     Color c = blue;

     if (c < 10.1) {             // compare Color with double !! 
         auto vec = getVector(c); // could be fine !!
     }
     ```

     However, `scoped enums` will be failed in this case.

     ```
     enum class Color{ blue, green, yellow };
     std::vector<std::size_t> getVector(std::size_t x);
     Color c = Color::blue;

     if (c < 10.1) {             // error !
         auto vec = getVector(c); // error !!
     }
     ```

     Fix it through `static_cast`

     ```
     if (static_cast<double>(c) < 10.1) {
        auto vec = getVector(static_cast<std::size_t>(c));
     }
     ```
   - `unscoped enums` may be forward-declared.

     ```
     enum Color;          // error!!
     enum class Color;    // fine
     ```
   - Both `scoped` and `unscoped` enums support specification of the underlying type. The default underlying type for `scoped enums` is `int`. `Unscoped enums` have no default underlying type.
2. **Using Concurrency API**

   - Prefer task-based to thread-based

     If you want to run a function `doAsyncWork` asynchronously, you have two basic choices. One is *thread-based*

     ```
     int doAsyncWork();
     std::thread t(doAsyncWork);
     ```

     The other is *task-based*.

     ```
     auto fut = std::async(doAsyncWork);
     ```

     Obviously, we can get the return value of `doAsyncWork` through *task-based* more easily than *thread-based*. With the `task-based` approach, it’s easy, because the future returned from `std::async` offers the get function. The `get` function is even more important if `doAsyncWork` emits an exception, because `get` provides access to that, too.
   - `Thread-based` calls for manual management of thread exhaustion, oversubscription, load balancing, and adaptation to new platforms.
     But `Task-based` via `std::async` with the default launch policy suffers from none of these drawbacks.

   Here are several links:

   [Concurrency In C++](https://paoloseverini.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/concurrency-in-c11/)

   [C/C++ Programming Abstractions for Parallelism and Concurrency](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/08/20/c-cpp11-concurrency/)

Comment: You may want to mention the other benefits of scoped enums. Also a discussion of what alternatives existed pre-c++11 wrt to concurrency would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Optimize simple mathematical functions with constexpr, especially if they are called inside inner loops. This would allow the compiler to calculate them at compilation saving you time

Example

```
constexpr int fibonacci(int i) {
    return i==0 ? 0 : (i==1 ? 1 : fibonacci(i-1) + fibonacci(i-2));
}
```

Another example is to use `std::enable_if` to limit the allowed template parameters types in a particular template function/class. This would make your code safer (in case you haven't use SFINAE to constrains the possible template arguments in your old code) when you implicit assume some property about the template types and it is just one extra line of code

example:

```
template
<
   typename T, 
   std::enable_if< std::is_abstract<T>::value == false, bool>::type = false // extra line
>
void f(T t) 
{ 
 // do something that depends on the fact that std::is_abstract<T>::value == false
}
```

Update 1: If you have a small array where the size is known at compile time and you you want to avoid the overhead of the heap allocation in std::vector (meaning: you want the array on the stack), you only choice in C++03 was to use c-style arrays. Change that to `std::array`. It is a simple change that provides you a lot of the functionally present in std::vector + stack allocation (much faster than heap allocation as I said before).

Comment: Never evaluate Fibonacci numbers in such way.

Comment: Not sure why, especially for F_N with N not very large (For large N probably there is more optimized formula). But here this is just proof of principle of what you can do with constexpr. I've already seen people advocating for constexpr versions of pow of small integer, log and sqrt, with some caveats. If you can do it at compile time a function called in a inner loop, it is is good optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Use smart pointers. Notice that there are still good reason to have naked pointers in some cases, the best way to check if a pointer should be smart is to look for the uses of `delete` on it.

There should be no reason to use `new` either. Replace every `new` with `make_shared` or `make_unique`.

Unfortunately `make_unique` [didn't make it in the C++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12580432/1708801), the best solution IMO is to implement it yourself(*see previous link*), and put some macros to check for the `__cplusplus` version (`make_unique` is available in C++14).

Using `make_unique` and `make_shared` is *really* important in order to make your code exception safe.

Comment: Directly assigning to a smart pointer is as safe as using those maker functions. If the smart pointer constructor throws, it deletes the constructed object. Still, make_shared could be optimized with a custom allocator+deallocator, so the bookkeeping for the shared pointer is prepended to the object.

Comment: *Directly assigning to a smart pointer is as safe as using those maker functions.*
It is not if you are passing the smart pointer as an argument to another function. See [this](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)

Comment: You mean, if you are passing the smart_pointer on construction as argument to a function, and you pass at least 1 more argument whose passing / construction can throw an exception, correct? Looks like both our comments need (inverse) qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Use of **override** keyword

Mark virtual functions in derived classes as override (if they indeed override of course). This can protect against introducing bugs in the future, e.g. by changing the signature of a virtual function in a base class and forgetting to change the signature in all derived classes accordingly.