# When to pass by reference for overloading operators in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, g++, operator-overloading

I have implemented a custom pointer class, lets call it japan. Here is a declaration and definition, as well as a main function I am trying to work with.

```
class japan
{

public:
japan(T *ptr) : ptr(ptr)
{}

T *get()
{
   return this->ptr;
}

bool operator==(const T *&other)
{
   return ( this->get() == other );
}
friend bool operator==(const T *&l, japan<T> r)
{
   return ( r == l );
}

private:
T *ptr;

};

int main(void)
{
    int j;
    int *k =  & j;
    japan<int> nihon(k);

    if(k == nihon)
        if(nihon == k)
           std::cout << "yay\n";

    if(nihon == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

     if(NULL == nihon)
        return 5;
  }
```

My == operator seem to working fine on actual T *s when they are passed in, however if I evoke it with NULL my compiler produces the errors:

```
stuff.cpp:40:15: error: no match for 'operator==' in '0l == nihon'
stuff.cpp:40:15: note: candidate is:
stuff.cpp:21:16: note: bool operator==(const int*&, japan<int>)
stuff.cpp:21:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'long int' to 'const int*&'
```

From what I understand... there should be some form of conversion from T * to  long int, or NULL's assignment operator would not function. I then reworked my operator a little.

Both of these functions work

```
friend bool operator==(T *l, japan<T> r);
friend bool operator==(const T *l, japan<T> r);
```

However This one fails.

```
friend bool operator==(const T *&l, japan<T> r);
```

This makes scene to me, changing NULL would change a value that is never used, but it is a const reference... so why does this fail. Is it common in c++ to not use references on boolean operators? Most of the examples I see always use a reference, but this seems like this would only work for lvalues... So is it better practice to pass by value while overloading?

ALSO:

Why would I get the warning :

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]

ptr.h:106:9: note: candidate 1: bool japan<T>::operator==(const T* const&) const [with T = Geometry]
stuff.cpp:239:15: note: candidate 2: operator==(int, long int) <built-in>
```

Is my japan class somehow exposing its self as a T when == is used, I ask this because I found this class in something I was working on with no == operator defined (despite it being used in many places), and I added one... only to find no end of problems.

Comment: That's not a const reference in the sense you're thinking of. It's a reference to a pointer to a `const T`.

Comment: I must be missing something, if it T was const it would be written as T * const right?

Comment: const T* is a pointer to a const T object  


T* const is a constant pointer to a non-constant T object  


const T* const is a const pointer to a const T object  



T const* and const T* are equivalent.

Comment: I think I see the const problem, I have updated the question in the ALSO section based on some new issues that have arisen.

Comment: Be careful while tagging: C++ templates are not the same (so far) as Java generics (A Turing Complete system vs some form of syntactic sugar :P)

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all?

Comment: @Manu343726 Thank you for the correction, some times these terms can be very confusing. To be honest, this japan class has had a lot of things removed from it. It is mainly used for scoping pointer to be safe when working with C spacial data libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In C++, 0 is an abused integer. It is used to reflect, well, 0 as a value of type int and it is also used to represent a null pointer.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-nullptr)

Your types are fundamentally different. There's no const correctness issue, it's just that NULL, is a macro for 0 and that's something that doesn't cooperate well with generic programming. You could try

```
static_cast<T*>(NULL);
```

when comparing with null pointer, or better yet use [nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21514913/2567683), which is what the new standard wants you to be using when you mean "a null pointer"

Comment: That and there's no valid conversion from `0` to `const int*&`, because temporaries only bind to const references.

Comment: Yes, 0 is an r value. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if instead of NULL, we'd use a global `const int NULLPTR = 0;` it could work but that would be terrible advise.

Comment: This seems to indicate the problem, it is unfortunate that C was based around ints.