# Does the constructor ignore portions of a member initialization list of an argument was supplied to the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to understand fully how a constructor works in C++.  Specifically, the member initialization list of a constructor.

Say you have a class Foobar with three data members bar, baz, and qux.

I set up my constructor like this:

```
Foobar(int bar, int baz, int qux)
    : bar(bar), baz(baz), qux(qux)
{
  // empty constructor body
}
```

My question is, does the member initialization list act as a "default"?  Or does it ALWAYS happen?  If, for example, the constructor was called with arguments, would the initialization list be ignored?
I want to always have the qux data member be 0, unless otherwise specified.  So would I instead write the member initialization line as:

```
  : nar(bar), bar(baz), qux(0)
```

Perhaps I'm totally misunderstanding the function of the member initialization list and maybe someone can set me straight.

Comment: I think your confusion is caused by the fact that your constructor's parameter names are the same as the member names. While this is legal, I would recommend you use different names, perhaps by simply prefixing your parameters with an underscore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Why use a silly underscore for a language rule that everybody knows about? #IdRatherNotUnderscore

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Because not everybody knows about it. And underscores aren't silly, they're fantastic.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley They have an implied meaning. That is nowhere near fantastic.

Comment: If they are strings instead of ints, does that change anything?  In my book they did this exactly, but they were strings...My understanding was that they were initialized to empty strings.

Comment: If you want default values I would suggest using [in class member intializers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24149924/1708801).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor cannot be called without arguments, as all three of them are required. The compiler will remind you if you forget.

If you always want to initialize a member to a fixed value, the way to do that is exactly what you propose.

Comment: You could also toss in the syntax for `qux = 0` as a default argument in your answer.