# C++11 aggregate initialization for classes with non-static member initializers

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, aggregate-initialization

Is it allowed in standard:

```
struct A
{
  int a = 3;
  int b = 3;
};

A a{0,1}; // ???
```

Is this class still aggregate?
`clang` accepts this code, but `gcc` doesn't.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In C++11 having in-class member initializers makes the struct/class not an aggregate — this was changed in C++14, however. This is something I found surprising when I first ran into it, the rationale for this restriction is that in-class initializers are pretty similar to a user defined constructor but the counter argument is that no one really expects that adding in-class initializers should make their class/struct a non-aggregate, I sure did not.

From the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `8.5.1` *Aggregates* (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), **no brace-or-equal initializers for non-static
>   data members** (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

and in [C++14](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) the same paragraph reads:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

This change is covered in [N3605: Member initializers and aggregates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html) which has the following abstract:

> Bjarne Stroustrup and Richard Smith raised an issue about aggregate
>   initialization and member-initializers not working together. This
>   paper **proposes to fix the issue by adopting Smith's proposed wording
>   that removes a restriction that aggregates can't have
>   member-initializers**.

This comment basically sums up the reluctance to allowing them to be aggregates:

> Aggregates cannot have user-defined constructors and
>   **member-initializers are essentially some kind of user-defined
>   constructor (element)** (see also Core Defect 886). I'm not against this
>   extension, but it also has implications on what our model of
>   aggregates actually is. After acceptance of this extension **I would
>   like to know how to teach what an aggregate is.**

The revised version [N3653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html) was adopted in [May 2013](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/).

**Update**

emsr points out that [G++ 5.0 now supports C++14 aggregates with non-static data member initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) using either `std=c++1y` or `-std=c++14`:

```
struct A { int i, j = i; };
A a = { 42 }; // a.j is also 42
```

See it working [live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oB5O8XE3DjHjOT2V).

Comment: So it seems like it is problem of not full Standard support by gcc

Comment: @Bikineev hmmm, what version of `gcc` are you using? I can not reproduce using `-std=c++11` using `gcc` from `4.7` to `4.9`. Can you clarify your question, you said that `clang` accepts it, I guess you meant `gcc`?

Comment: I use gcc 4.9.1. I meant gcc doesn't support this change from proposal. I get:"error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'"

Comment: @Bikineev ok, so you must be using `-std=c+1y` which will work for `clang` but won't in `gcc`. I can not get this to work in `clang` using `-std=c++11`, which is correct.

Comment: @Bikineev: You have to tell GCC which standard to use. Alas, indeed at least [GCC 4.9.0 doesn't support this in C++14 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75676726c087620c).

Comment: C++14 aggregate initiaizers were only just added to [gcc 5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html).  This feature will be available with -std=c++1y or -std=c++14.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thank you for such extensive response!