# g++ 4.9 rejects valid aggregate initialization in C++14

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

Consider this code:

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    double y = 1.1;
};

int main()
{
    S s = {0};
}
```

According to the C++14 standard, § 8.5.1/7

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equal- initializer, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

the code should be perfectly valid.

However, g++ 4.9.2 rejects the code (compiled with `-std=c++14`)

```
so.cpp:9:13: error: could not convert '{0}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'S'
     S s = {0};
```

clang++ on the other hand compiles it.

Is this a known issue for g++?

Comment: gcc 5.0 [works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/u87I6PIXszy1sw1K) ... likely a bug that is now fixed

Comment: `S` is not an aggregate until C++14 (in C++11, aggregates cannot have NSDMIs). If you look at the [GCC C++14 feature table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) you'll see that this feature isn't implemented until GCC 5.

Comment: @T.C. thanks for the link, should have checked before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, this is valid C++14; however, in C++11 a class with [in class member initializers was not an aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) and so this is not valid in C++11.

The issue as I noted in my answer to the above question and I realized later after I made my initial comment is that [gcc did not support this change until 5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/u87I6PIXszy1sw1K)*):

> G++ now supports C++14 aggregates with non-static data member
>   initializers.
>
> ```
> struct A { int i, j = i; };
> A a = { 42 }; // a.j is also 42
> ```