# C++ initializer list and default values

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

Is this code valid with C++14

```
using namespace std;
struct Point
{
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
};
Point p2 {1, 1};
```

It compiles fine with clang++ 7.0, it doesn't work with G++ 4.9 in both cases I pass --std=c++1y to the compiler.

In G++ it works when I remove the default values from the struct definition.

```
g++ test_constexpr_ctor.cc --std=c++1y -o test
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:7:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Point::Point(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
Point p2 {1, 1};
            ^
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:7:15: note: candidates are:
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note: constexpr Point::Point()
struct Point
        ^
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note: constexpr Point::Point(const Point&)
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note: constexpr Point::Point(Point&&)
test_constexpr_ctor.cc:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: Most probably a gcc 4.9 bug.

Comment: It is a bug of old g++. Update it to a newer version and it compiles succesfully.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy what G++ version did you test?

Comment: `g++ 5.1.0` is enough.

Comment: @101010 yes it is a bug, see [C++11 aggregate initialization for classes with non-static member initializers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) and [g++ 4.9 rejects valid aggregate initialization in C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28113750/1708801) ... last looks like a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is valid.

1. (8.5.4/3):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type
>   T
>   is defined as follows:
>   —
>    If
>   T
>   is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed

2. An aggregate in c++14 is defined as (8.5.1/1):

> An
>   aggregate
>   is an array or a class (Clause
>    9
>   ) with no user-provided constructors (
>   12.1
>   ), no private or
>   protected non-static data members (Clause
>    11
>   ), no base classes (Clause
>    10
>   ), and no virtual functions (
>   10.3
>   ).

Note that in c++11 this definition looked different (emphasis mine):

> An
>   aggregate
>   is an array or a class (Clause
>    9
>   ) with no user-provided constructors (
>   12.1
>   ), **no
>   brace-or-equal-
>   initializer
>   s for non-static data members (
>   9.2
>   )**, no private or protected non-static data members (Clause
>    11
>   ),
>   no base classes (Clause
>    10
>   ), and no virtual functions (
>   10.3
>   ).

Since this part is removed in c++14, your struct is definitely an aggregate and thus aggregate initialization should be performed.

This is [fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) in gcc5 (search the changes list for "aggregates with non-static data member initializers"). I wouldn't call it a "bug" though, it's rather the gcc team only implemented that change in gcc 5.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is absolutely correct.

However the behaviour you have is a [not yet closed bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62165) of G++ version 4.9.1. Actually, it may be a duplicate and closed in some other bug report, because the problem is fixed since `g++` **5.1.0** or maybe even earlier version. To find actual bug you may use [bugzilla's search](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=aggregate).