# How to initialize a class like std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11, stl, initialization, stdarray

I'm trying to write a container class for vector arithmetic. The objects are static in size:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
class vec{
    T data[N] = {0};
public:
    vec(std::initializer_list<T> ini){
        std::copy(ini.begin(), ini.end(), data);
    }
}
```

This is how far I got.

But than I tested the std::array class for comparison and I noticed that it somehow could make a static assertion if the initializer list was to long or to short.

```
std::array<float, 2> a = {1, 2, 3, 4} <- instant error message from the visual studio ide
```

In my class I would have to check the length of the initializer list at run-time.

I assume, that the std::array class somehow manages it to directly initialize the data with the initializer list notation without the std::initializer_list class.

Is it possible to initialize my class in the same way as std::array?

Comment: One reason your vec won't allow it is the fact that T data[n] is private...make it public, then get rid of the constructor. Further, your sample line for std::array above does compile if you include the closing ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is an aggregate and so it uses [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Providing excess elements during aggregate initialization is ill-formed and requires a diagnostic. The compiler at minimum has to provide a warning, both gcc and clang make this an error. So if you make your class an aggregate then you can have it work the same way std::array does. Note, [in class member initializers makes your class a non-aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) in C++11 but not in C++14.

We can see it is an aggregate by going to the draft C++11 standard section `23.3.2.1` *[array.overview]*:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax
>
> ```
> array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
> ```
>
> where initializer-list is a comma-separated list of up to N elements
>   whose types are convertible to T.

and section `8.5.1` *[dcl.init.aggr]* covers aggregate intialization and says:

> An initializer-list is ill-formed if the number of initializer-clauses
>   exceeds the number of members or elements to initialize.

The draft standard provides for exposition a possible implementation which shortened to the bare minimum looks like this:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
struct array {
    T elems[N];
};
```

and the draft standard has a note which says:

> The member variable elems is shown for exposition only, to emphasize that array is a class aggregate.
>   The name elems is not part of array’s interface

which is an aggregate and will with both gcc and clang provide an error if excess elements are provided.

Also see [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/1708801).