# What's wrong with this inline initialization of std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, g++

Consider the following declaration:

```
#include <array>

struct X
{
    //std::array<bool,3> arr={false,false,false};
    bool brr[3]={false,false,false};
};
```

As is, it compiles normally by g++ 5.2. But if I uncomment the `std::array`, I get an error:

```
test.cpp:5:46: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     std::array<bool,3> arr={false,false,false};
                                              ^
test.cpp:5:46: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<bool, 3u>’
```

OTOH, this declaration works without problems inside `main()`. Also, the following initialization does work inside `struct X`:

```
std::array<bool,3> arr={{false,false,false}};
```

Why can't I use the simple initialization with single braces in struct definition?

Comment: Note, in C++11 as opposed to C++14 having in class initializers [makes the strut a non-aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This looks like a gcc bug see: [Bug 65815 - brace elision doesn't work in NSDMI](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65815). The report says:

> On Page 975 of "The C++ Programming Language", 4th edition, Bjarne
>   Stroustrup says:
>
> "An array can be initialized by an initializer list: array a1 =
>   { 1, 2, 3 };"
>
> and Clang (V 3.5) accepts it. However, G++ 4.9.2 thinks this is an
>   error:
>
> ```
> "error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
>    const std::array<double, 3> _ar0val = {1.0, -1.0, 1.0};"
> ```

The issue was narrowed down to the following test case:

```
struct array {
  int data [2];
};

struct X {
  array a = { 1, 2 };
};
```

It looks like the fix is in the head revision, the OPs code works in that revision, [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UsIG78qY3rMDrPjJ).

As noted in the bug report using an inner set of braces is a possible work-around:

```
std::array<bool,3> arr={ {false,false,false} };
                         ^                 ^
```