# Why do clang and gcc handle braced-initialization of structs with in-class initialization differently?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++14

I recently discovered an odd behavior of clang and gcc. I have a struct (`MyClass`) which uses in-class initialization for one of its members (`active`):

```
struct MyClass {
  int something;
  bool active = true;
};
```

Now I try to brace-initialize this class.

Using clang, I can decide whether I include `active` in the initializer list (`MyClass a = { 42, true};`) or not (`MyClass a = { 42 };`).

However using gcc, my code only compiles if I do not include `active`. Else, I will get the following compiler error:

```
 error: could not convert ‘{42, true}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘MyClass’
```

Is this a bug? What does the standard say about it? What about VSC++? Which way would you recommend as the portable solution?

Tested using gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5 on Debian Linux.

Comment: Are you compiling in C++14 mode for both?

Comment: Yes, I do. I also enabled all warnings `-Wall`, but don't get a single one.

Comment: In C++11 a class with [non-static in-class member initializers is not an aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) and so this will fail in C++11 mode but should succeed in C++14 mode for both. As I note in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27118551/1708801) to the  linked question gcc did not support this till 5.0.

Comment: @melak47 see my note above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour of this code changed between C++11 and C++14.

In C++11 the presence of `= true` means that the class was not an aggregate. Therefore you could not use aggregate initialization.

In C++14 the class is still an aggregate, so you can use aggregate initialization again.

The difference between compilers could be explained by one being newer than the other.  Using [compiler explorer](http://goo.gl/NGqDt6) I see that gcc 4.9.x gets it wrong , but this is fixed in gcc 5.1 .

Comment: Using clang in c++11 mode supports this hypothesis. It complains about the same things as gcc.

Comment: My guess is that this is technically a bug in C++11 mode in clang - although one that is mostly harmless unless you are specifically looking for an error when this construct is used.

Comment: @MatsPetersson it seems correct in clang and bugged in g++

Comment: @M.M: Uh, is the code supposed to compile in C++11 mode, then? My comment was to OP's comment that in C++11 mode, it still compiles in clang...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I assume he meant that the code fails in clang -std=c++11 and succeeds in clang -std=c++14 , which is the correct behaviour (compiler explorer seems to bear this out)