# syntax for initializing nested member in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

When compiling the following code:

**foo.h**:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct external_class;

struct A {
    struct B {
        std::vector<external_class> bad_vector;
    };
    std::vector<external_class> good_vector;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    A();
};
```

**foo.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h":

struct external_class {};     // implement external_class

A::A() : 
    good_vector(),            // <- easy to initialize via default constructor
    b(std::make_shared<B>())  // <- does not involve bad_vector::ctor -> warning
{ }

int main() { A a; }
```

.. with the `-Weffc++` flag (gcc) I get the warning

```
foo.cpp:9:12: warning: ‘A::B::bad_vector’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     struct B {
            ^
```

Which is totally clear to me but I wonder how I should get rid of it.

For dependency reasons I need the forward declaration for `external_class`, so in-class-initialization is not possible. I could provide a constructor for `A::B` and implement it inside `foo.cpp` but I still hope there is a very short way to initialize `A::b` by providing an initializer for `A::B::bad_vector` (similar to `A::good_vector`).

Is that right? What's the syntax (and should I have googled for to find the solution?) Or do I have to provide a constructor for `B`?

Comment: @juanchopanza [Not true](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-3)

Comment: Maybe I have to add a thing: `A::good_vector` would really be a problem without the actual definition.  In my example it only shows the way I'd like to initialize `A::B::bad_vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine.

The warning is basically about `B` not having a constructor that explicitly default-initializes `bad_vector`. But the default constructor for `B` already default-initializes `bad_vector`. Even `B() = default;` doesn't silence the warning, you actually have to write out `B() : bad_vector() { }`. That to me suggests that `-Weffc++` may be obsolete in C++11.

Comment: So there isn't a way to initialize `A::B::bad_vector` inside `A::A()` via something _like_ an initializer list for `A::b`?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be? a) user-defined constructor b) aggregate initialization

Comment: What would aggregate initialization look like in this example? I think this term is what I've been looking for but I how I would do it in this case.

Comment: @Barry: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27118551/1668622) answer tell me that what I'd like to do is possible with C++14?