# Why is second initialization allowed in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Under C++11 it is possible to initialize class members directly upon declaration. But it is also ok to initialize them once more in the initialization list of the constructor... why?

```
#include <iostream>



struct MyStr
{

    MyStr()
    :j(0)
    {
        std::cout << "j is " << j << std::endl; // prints "j is 0"
    }

    const int j = 1;

};

int main()
{
    const int i = 0;

    MyStr mstr; 
}
```

Because doing something like this is an error, understandably:

```
MyStr()
:j(0),
j(1)
{
}
```

What is different about the first example, where the data member gets initialized upon declaration and then again in the constructor's init list?

Comment: There is only ever *one* initialization.

Comment: See [Has the new C++11 member initialization feature at declaration made initialization lists obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24149924/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that an individual constructor may override it.

From [the original feature proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm):

> It may happen that a data member will usually have a particular value, but a few specialized constructors will need to be cognizant of that value. If a constructor initializes a particular member explicitly, the constructor initialization overrides the member initializations as shown below: *[..]*

Remember, you can have more than one constructor.

Answer (score 10):

Only *one* initialization actually happens. It's just that you're allowed to write a "default" one in the form of the *brace-or-equals initializer*, but if your constructor initializer list specifies an initializer, too, that one is the only one that's used.

As a side note, as of C++14, a *brace-or-equals initializer* can be provided for a non-static data member of an aggregate (which cannot have constructors).