# Non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++

> `[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Below I have used `//` to show that three lines of code where I got the error, despite the code working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Bank
{
  private:
    char name[20];
    int accNo;
    char x;
    double balance;
    double amount;
    float interestRate;
    float servCharge = 5;  //[Warning]
    float count = 0;  //[Warning] 
    bool status = true;  //[Warning]

  public:
    void openAccount();
    void depositMoney();
    void withdrawMoney();
    void checkBalance_info();
    void calcInt();
    void monthlyProc();
};

void Bank::calcInt() {
cout << " Enter your annual interestRate : " << endl;
cin >> interestRate;

double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12;
double monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
balance += monthlyInterest;

cout << "Updated Balance After Monthly interestRate " << balance << endl;

if (balance < 25){
   status = true;
}

void Bank :: monthlyProc(){  
  if (balance < 25){
    status = false;
  }   
  while (count > 4){
    balance = balance - 1;
  }
  servCharge = servCharge + (count * 0.10);
  balance -= servCharge;
  cout << "Monthly Service Charges: " << servCharge <<endl;
  cout << "Updated Balance After Monthly interestRate " << balance << endl;
}
```

Also, I did not include the whole code cause it is a bit longer. Please tell me if I need to upload the whole code. Just need help to make the code run without any sort of error.

Comment: [Default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) are only supported since C++11. In other words, the code would fail to compile in C++03 or C++98 mode. To silence the warning you need to tell the compiler that you *meant* to use the C++11 language standard, presumably by adding the applicable `-std` switch.

Comment: Just as a tip and for future reference, please indent your code for readability reasons...

Comment: I edited your code with good indentation practices to give your code structure which helps to make it readable which is extremely important especially when others are reading, reviewing, or editing your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float servCharge = 5; //[Warning]

float count = 0;//[Warning] 

bool status = true;//[Warning]
```

Those are warnings, not errors. It means that you are initialising those member variables in-class but those are not static members. This was a limitation of older C++98 and C++03.

You may eliminate those warnings in two ways:

(1) Do exactly what the compiler wants you to do, ie specifying these option when compiling your code:

```
-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11  // using newer C++11
```

(2) Do initialise those in-class definition, instead using initialising them using the old way ie. using the constructor:

```
Bank::Bank() : servCharge(5), count(0), status(true)
{
   //..
}
```