# Why could const member be initialized twice?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, constants, initializer-list

Below is a code snippet which could be compiled and run without error in vs2015

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        A(int b) :k(b) {}//second time
    const int k = 666;//first time
};

int main() {
    A a(555);
    cout << a.k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `555`. But as far as I know,`const` object should be initialized only once,after which the value is unmodifiable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has the new C++11 member initialization feature at declaration made initialization lists obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149924/has-the-new-c11-member-initialization-feature-at-declaration-made-initializati)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's not initialized twice; the [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) is just ignored. So for `A a(555);`, `a.k` is initialized as `555`.

> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor, the default member initializer is ignored.

From the standard, [[class.base.init]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#10):

> If a given non-static data member has both a default member
>   initializer and a [*mem-initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer), the initialization specified by the
>   [*mem-initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer) is performed, and the non-static data member's default
>   member initializer is ignored. [ [*Example*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#10.example-1): Given
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   int i = /* some integer expression with side effects */ ;
>   A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
>   // ...
> };
> ```
>
> the `A(int)` constructor will simply initialize `i` to the value of `arg`,
>   and the side effects in `i`'s default member initializer will not take
>   place. — *end example* ]

On the other hand, given

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}            // k will be initialized via default member initializer, i.e. 666
    A(int b) :k(b) {} // k will be initialized via member initializer list, i.e. b

    const int k = 666;
};
```

then for `A a;`, `a.k` will be initialized as `666`.

Comment: Where is that quote from? I'm not disputing it - it would just be nice to properly reference it.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson It's from the link I posted in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping it was something from the standard.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Done.

Comment: That's really interesting, especially the loss of side-effects.

Answer (score 8):

It is initialized only once.

```
const int k = 666;
```

would be used if not provided in constructor.

Comment: What's the advised style: putting the default value that way, or as a default parameter value in the constructor?

Comment: In the class definition. Use the constructor if it makes sense to specialize the value.

Comment: @user1997744 Using default member initializer as the default value, especially when there're multiple constructors; using member initializer list when want to overwrite them.