# Force inlining a recursive function

Tags: c++, gcc, inline

Consider the classic way of defining a factorial function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((always_inline)) inline int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("value %d", factorial(7/*guaranteed to not overflow int*/));
}
```

I'm forcing my compiler (gcc) to inline the factorial function. That *should* cause a problem. gcc is ignoring my force inline without error. Is this expected?

Comment: recursive function can't be inline functions. I think the compiler is ignoring your "attribute" because of this

Comment: @Agostino: If you read the question, the OP know it, that's why he asked this...

Comment: Since you called factorial with a constant, how do you know it wasn't inlined?  I don't know if gcc is that smart.  When I tested icc many years (and versions ago) it wasn't that smart (such optimizations of constants occurred after, not intermixed with inlining).  But maybe gcc now is smarter than icc then.

Comment: @Agostino Interesting, but I thought inline recursive functions could be changed into loops untill certain depths, effectively inlining the recursive function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190232/can-a-recursive-function-be-inline).

Comment: @FlorisVelleman wow, I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: @FlorisVelleman Optimising the calls out of recursive functions is head- and tail-call optimisation, not inlining. Not sure if gcc is smart enough to work that out, but something like `int fact(int x, int y) { return x == 1 ? y : fact(x - 1, x * y); }` might work... This is irrelevant to `inline`.

Comment: @Seb There seems to be something going on in using the `inline` keyword for these examples though: http://goo.gl/5lFsfP (with), http://goo.gl/zye7Zt (without). It changes the output quite drastically (not using tail call elimination).

Comment: @FlorisVelleman What did you conclude regarding `static` versus `extern` (default)? Also, you got the arguments around the wrong way.

Comment: Have you tried using [constexpr like in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851456/1708801). If you arguments are constant expressions it should be able to perform the operation at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

From GCC's documentation:

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you specify the `always_inline` attribute for the function.

So `always_inline` doesn't mean "inline this or diagnose", it means "inline even if optimizations are off". It will still refuse to inline something if it's not possible or reasonable.

As you can see [here](http://goo.gl/HtRWxj), for an example as simple as yours the whole function can be optimised out and the result calculated at compile-time. Even if the argument is not a compile-time constant, the function can still be [inlined](http://goo.gl/ebSKOx). Recursion doesn't *always* make inlining impossible.

However, as pointed out by [Floris Velleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948895/floris-velleman), if you turn optimizations off it will [fail to compile](http://goo.gl/P0jDfR), stating that the function is not considered for inlining, even though it will inline it if optimizations are on. Seems like the actual handling of the attribute is not fully consistent with the documentation.

Comment: Nice answer, interesting how this results in a compile-time error if you happen to compile it without optimizations, seems like `constexpr` is a better fit if you happen to work with compile-time constants.