# C++ template metaprogramming: constexpr function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I was watching Bjarne Stroustrup's talk "[The Essential C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86xWVb4XIyE)".

In Q&A session, on how to manage heavy template programming codes, he mentioned that: "by *constack perfunction* you can eliminate essentially every template metaprogramming that generates a value by writting ordinary code".

The *constack perfunction* is just a wild guess by the sound.

May I ask what is the correct term for that technology? so that I could do some follow up reading.

update: just modify the title to "constexpr function".

Comment: `constexpr` function?

Comment: Please see if you can get transcript of his talk.. you are adding too many questions from same talk in a row!! man.

Comment: Probably constexpr function, I give an example of how to replace template meta-programming with constexpr functions in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21519186/1708801). My example comes from [Want speed? Use constexpr meta-programming!](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/07/want-speed-use-constexpr-meta.html) which is a good article on the topic.

Comment: constack perfunction: (v) An upside-down stack (constack) for each function (perfunction).  Also, not actual words.

Comment: That's over an hour and a half - did you want us to listen to the entire thing for your single sentence?!

Comment: @PranitKothari let's say it's a stream flush :p i do a batch job, list the things i don't understand, then try to figure it out by my own, then the rest, seek help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`constexpr` functions, added in C++11, can be evaluated at compile-time and be used as template arguments in template metaprogramming. In C++11 they are very limited and can (nearly) only consist of a single `return` expression. C++14 makes them less restrictive.

For example this is possible:

```
constexpr std::size_t twice(std::size_t sz) {
    return 2 * sz;
}

std::array<int, twice(5)> array;
```

Whereas before C++11, template 'hacks' were needed, like for instance:

```
template<std::size_t sz>
class twice {
public:
    static const std::size_t value = 2 * sz;
}

std::array<int, twice<5>::value> array;
```

It can for instance be used to generate values (like math constants, trigonometric lookup tables, ...) at compile-time in a clean manner.