# Defining a value to a varibale declared in class

Tags: c++

I was working with inheritance in C++ but I found the following error: 's' does not name a type.

Can someone please explain what is the problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
public:
    int s,i;
    i=10;
};
class b:public a
{
public:
void print()
{
    cout<<s;
}
};
int main()
{
    b o;
    o.print();
}
```

Comment: please help i need to finish this soon

Comment: You mean `'i' does name a type`. You cannot assign variable in the class body like that; You should do it in the constructor (or during the declaration like this `int i = 10;`, but don't do it). [Some examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list); And don't post "please help" - it never makes people willing to help you.

Comment: but why is that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the reason for initializing fields inside class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582045/whats-the-reason-for-initializing-fields-inside-class)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused as to why your compiler gives you that *particular* error, but there *is* an error in your code.  You can't put executable statements like `i=10;` as 'free-standing' parts of your class definition; generally, any such code must be part of the body of a member function.

However, you *can* provide a default (initial) value for variables *in their declaration*. So, you could do this (I've also added an 'arbitrary' initial value for the `s` variable, so you can see that the code is working):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;

class a {
public:
    int s = 42, i = 0; // You can put initial (i.e. default) values for the members in the declarations
    // i = 10; // Can't have this line here
};
class b :public a {
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << s;
    }
};
int main()
{
    b o;
    o.print();
}
```

Please also read this post: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: i want to ask one more thing when i print value of s in base class i dont get the value assinged to it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: `s` in the base class is the same as `s` in the derived class, and that shows the value `42`, does it not?

Comment: no i mean when i initialize it through object creation and not like what i asked(that was a diffrent problem) now i ask if i assign a value to s through object of class a why cant i directly acess that value in class b

Comment: Again, I'm not *entirely* sure what you mean. Although you can (sometimes) access a derived class 'as though it were' its base class, trying to do the other way round will generally be problematical. Maybe post as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

For in your snipe of code. You are trying to initialize class variable within class whereas you can initialize the variable in constructor or setter function like following

```
class a
{
public:
    int s, i;
    a()
    {
        i = 10;
        s = 20;
    };
    void setS(int a)
    {
        s = a;
    }
};
class b :public a
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << s;
    }
};
int main()
{
    b o;
    o.print();
}
```