# Equating inside Structure

Tags: c, linux

I have doubt on writing structure like this.
Why here we have to equate some thing to some other thing (.owner = THIS_MODULE)

```
const struct file_operations nvram_fops = {
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        .llseek         = nvram_llseek,
        .read           = read_nvram,
        .write          = write_nvram,
        .ioctl          = nvram_ioctl,
};
```

PLease help on this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: C++ doesn't have designated initialisers, so I'm removing the C++ tag.

Comment: Dupilcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016107/what-is-tagged-structure-initialization-syntax

Answer (score 3):

This is initialization syntax.

Here, `nvram_fops` is a structure of type `file_operations`. Its `owner` field is set to `THIS_MODULE`, `llseek` to `nvram_llseek` and so on.

If you are trying to understand the code at a higher level, take a look at ["The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide"](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm). It explains that

> The `file_operations` structure is defined in `linux/fs.h`, and holds pointers to functions defined by the driver that perform various operations on the device. Each field of the structure corresponds to the address of some function defined by the driver to handle a requested operation.