# C++ Initialize object member of a struct that is allocated using the "new" keyword

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

This may be a complicated question but I assume it has a simple answer.

So I have a struct that contains custom object types:

```
// header1.h

struct MyStruct
{
    MyClass myObject1;
    MyClass myObject2;
};
```

And I have a global pointer to a MyStruct. I am going to allocate and instantiate the struct using the `new` keyword. When I do so, I want to construct each myObject by name in an initializer list, as shown below.

```
// codeFile1.cpp

MyStruct *myStructPtr;

int main()
{
    myStructPtr = new MyStruct
    {                                     //syntax error: missing ';'
        .myObject1 = MyClass(arg1, arg2),
        .myObject2 = MyClass(arg1, arg2)
    };
}
```

The code snippet above has syntax errors, but it demonstrates what I want to do. Note that MyClass does not have a default constructor, so it must be given an argument list.

Thanks!

**EDIT - CONCLUSION**

As pointed out, my initialization list is C-style, which fails to work. Unfortunately the C++11 initializer-list does not meet my compiler requirements, and the option of throwing all arguments into a constructor is not practical.

So I took an alternative solution and changed the pointer structure to the following:

```
// header1.h

struct MyStruct
{
    MyClass *myObjectPtr1;
    MyClass *myObjectPtr2;
};

// codeFile1.cpp

MyStruct myStruct;

int main()
{
    myStructPtr.myObjectPtr1 = new MyClass(arg1, arg2);
    myStructPtr.myObjectPtr2 = new MyClass(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Is `MyStruct` an aggregate? If not, you need to provide a constructor.

Comment: `;` at the end o the struct, please !

Comment: Also, what you have shown here is `C`'s [tagged struct initialization syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016107/what-is-tagged-structure-initialization-syntax). C++ doesn't support it.

Comment: @Pradhan I believe so. It is parallel to the the code shown here, the only significant difference is the number of members.

Comment: BTW your domain name is broken

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That happened a while ago, yes. Forgot to edit it from my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use C's designated initializers, which [are not part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18731707/241631). If you have a C++11 compiler, you can simply do the following:

```
MyStruct *myStructPtr = new MyStruct
{
    MyClass(arg1, arg2),
    MyClass(arg1, arg2)
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2590533372bbadb)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could do this in general. Which list initialization clause covers this? when `MyStruct` isn't an aggregate? Running through the conditions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), I am unable to understand why this is allowed.

Comment: What makes this possible in C++11 but not earlier?

Comment: @Pradhan It's the same as your answer, in fact, I like your answer better because you avoided mentioning `MyClass`

Comment: @aaronncfca It requires list initialization which is part of C++11

Answer (score 3):

If `MyStruct` is an aggregate, you could use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to avoid defining a constructor:

```
myStructPtr = new MyStruct {{arg1, arg2}, {arg1, arg2}};
```

If not, please provide a constructor taking the appropriate arguments and call

```
myStructPtr = new MyStruct{arg1, arg2};
```

Comment: Using the aggregate initialization doesn't get rid of the "missing ';'" syntax error. Also seing a "MyStruct: no appropriate default constructor available" on the same line.

Comment: This is _not_ aggregate initialization, guys.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not sure what I am missing. From N3797, `8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]`, the first point says that the above initializer expression for the `new` is *list initialization*. The third point in the same section says `If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed`. And my answer opens with the assumption that `MyStruct` is an aggregate.

Comment: `[C++11: 8.5.1/1]:` "An _aggregate_ is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no _brace-or-equal-initializers_ for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3)."

Comment: Fair enough, though: _if_ `MyStruct` were an aggregate then it would be aggregate initialisation (TIL) so, although misleading, your answer is not strictly wrong the way it is worded. Just testing! ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am offended! My answer has an if clause and an else clause :)

Answer (score 1):

You will, somehow, need to chain your constructions together. Assuming you actually want the same arguments:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(int arg1, int arg2) : myObject(arg1, arg2), myObejct2(arg1, arg2) {}
    MyClass myObject1;
    MyClass myObject2;
};

MyStruct *s = new MyStruct(34, 42);
```

Or something like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(const MyClass& a1, const MyClass& a2) : myObject(a1), myObejct2(a2) {}
 .... 
};

MyStruct *s = new MyStruct(MyClass(1,2), MyClass(3,4));
```

or in C++11 initializer lists:

```
MyStruct *s = new MyStruct({1,2}, {3,4});
```

Many other similar solutions are available.

Comment: I have about 50 members in the real MyStruct each with several arguments in the constructor, so this is not viable for me.

Comment: wouldn't it also work doing: ... `MyStruct *s = new MyStruct({1,2}, {3,4});` ?

Comment: @aaronncfca: Maybe you could post the REAL code then, not something you just made up to post here - but that sounds like you probably don't want to initialize with an initializer list in that way anyway...

Comment: @aaron 50 members?! Are you sure your classes are not _wildly_ too large?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a list of objects that I wanted to put in a struct to keep better manageable.

Comment: @aaron It's an extremely long list. Consider rethinking it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How else would you suggest storing such a list of objects? They need to be globally accessible and dynamically allocated.

Comment: @aaronncfca: There are like a million ways you could do it. An answer to that question could fill a book. Speaking books which one are you using?

Comment: Give REAL code, and we MAY be able to offer more useful advice. But it generally seems wrong to have 50 objects in a single struct.

Comment: Would it be superior to have all of them in global scope? The purpose in the struct is to minimize the number of global variables, which I feel is good practice (possibly for JavaScript reasons).

Comment: Really can't answer that without understanding what you are doing. 50 odd things that are global seems wrong either way.